# A has many B's, and only one 'active' B

Tags: database, database-design

Say, `User` has many `Devices`. That is, `Device.user_id references User.id`.

We need to add 'active' status to user-device relation. This means that a `User` can have no more than one 'active' `Device`.

-- addendum

It seems I have to clarify things.

- A `User` can actially have no `Device`s, one `Device`, or several `Device`s;
- `Device` can have an owning `User`, but must not;
- that 'ownership' is that reference `Device.user_id references User.id`;
- `User.id` and `Device.id` are the only PKs and must not change (so, *no* composite PKs);
- A `User` can have *no more then one* 'active' `Device`, but it can be `NULL`, but if not `NULL`, it must reference one of the `Device`s this `User` owns.

-- end addendum

I can imagine two approaches, both very straightforward:

1. add a `active_device_id` field to `User`, that is `User.active_device_id references Device.id`;
2. add a `Boolean`-type flag to `Device` entity.

The most common queries are:

- select an active `Device` for the given `User`;
- check if current `Device` is active for the owning `User`;

Rarely used, but very important are:

- make a given `Device` active for the owning `User` (and make other `User`'s devices inactive);
- change the ownership of a given `Device`.

The 1st approach has two caveats:

- `user1` has active device set to `device1`, but `device1` is owned by `user2`;
- both `user1` and `user2` have the same active `device` (though it could be easily fixed by a unique constraint on the field `User.active_device_id`.

The 2d approach coul lead to several active `Device`s for one `User`.

What are other the disadvantages of both approaches?

...and what should I choose and why? :)

Comment: You can still choose to implement both. It's a duplication of data, but helps your 2 queries. You can maintain the state on write operations.

Comment: GaborSch, I dont' see the reason for implementing both, as soon as in 99% cases quering Devices is done with joininin them with Users.

Comment: Depending on your DBMS you could create a partial unique index on the device table.

Comment: You never described how the Owning user of a device is set/determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go for the first approach -- the active_device_id.

It enables a guarantee of only one active device per user, and as you say allows an optional guarantee of uniqueness of active device id across all users.

All of the queries are very straightforward with this method.

Comment: Personally I like the first approach best, too :)

Comment: Can you help me understand how this guarantees only one active device per user?

Comment: Each use only has one record in the users table, so only one value can be stored in the active_device_id column per user.

Comment: @DavidAldridge [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11dca/1) is how I interpret your answer.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Yes -- the schema naturally constrains the data to allow only one active device per user. The reverse constraint (a device to be active for only one user) would be guaranteed with a unique constraint on user.active_device_id.

Comment: @DavidAldridge The way I'm interpreting OP's requirements is that they are attempting to enforce that each user has a *unique* device.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO you mean that each device can be active for only one user, I think. I address that in the answer: "... and as you say allows an optional guarantee of uniqueness of active device id across all users." The questioner raised that implementation himself -- I'm just confirming that it can easily be implemented.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Quote from the OP: _"`User` has many `Devices`"_.

Comment: I think I choose the first approach right now. Maybe we will use Redis later for that - not sure right now (we already use Redis for some simple caching)

Comment: P.S. And noone noticed there is a circular dependency ;)

Comment: @saabeilin It's not really a circular dependency, I think, unless a user must always have an active device ANd a device must always have an owner.

Comment: Formally, it is; in most cases, User and Device are added at one time, with that Device being owned by this User and active.

Comment: Even a circular dependency need not be a fatal problem -- some RDBMSs allow constraint enforcement to be deferred until commit.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your DBMS but most DBMS have the possibility to create partial indexes and this seems like a perfect use case for them.

I'm a bit confused how your device table looks like, but assuming the structure:

```
create table device
(
   device_id           integer not null,
   user_id             integer not null,
   is_active_for_user  boolean, 
   primary key (device_id, user_id)
);
```

You can ensure that each user has exactly one active device using the following index (Postgres syntax, other DBMS have other syntax to define a partial index):

```
create unique index idx_unique_active_device 
    on device (user_id)
    where is_active_for_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to enforce one **unique** device per user, all you need is a unique constraint on the referenced `deviceId` column in your `user` table. There is no need for flags.

```
device
------
id

user
------
id
deviceId (fk, unique constraint)
```

If you follow [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19160515/679449) approach, there is no guarantee of only one active device per user. You must have a `UNIQUE` constraint to guarantee one device per user:

This will allow duplicate devices:

```
CREATE TABLE device (
  `id` int,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO device (`id`)
VALUES (1), (2);

CREATE TABLE user (
  `id` int, 
  `active_device_id` int,
  INDEX (`active_device_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`active_device_id`)
    REFERENCES `device`(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO user (`id`, `active_device_id`)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);
```

Adding the `UNIQUE` guarantees each user will have a *unique* device.

```
CREATE TABLE device (
  `id` int,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO device (`id`)
VALUES (1), (2);

CREATE TABLE user (
  `id` int, 
  `active_device_id` int,
  INDEX (`active_device_id`),
  UNIQUE (`active_device_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`active_device_id`)
    REFERENCES `device`(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO user (`id`, `active_device_id`)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);
-- Duplicate entry '1' for key 'active_device_id_2':
```

Comment: As soon as both `User` and `Device` tables are already accompanied by their respective history tables, and that history is rarely used, it seems too heavyweight to have an intermediate table?

Comment: @saabeilin The "intermediate" table is meant for a `m:n` relationship. This means that each user can have a list of *possible* active devices, and one flagged as active. I wasn't sure what your specific goal was. Otherwise, go with the second design in my answer.

Comment: @saabeilin I think it just hit me. What you should do is just force a unique constraint on the `deviceId`, eliminating the need for a flag. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Every device is a *possible* active device, but you must first become the owner and then make it active :)

Comment: Changing your answer so drastically puts the previous comments out of context -- better to add a new answer, optionally deleting the previous one.

Comment: You're confusing "only one active device per user" with "only one user per active device".

Comment: @DavidAldridge That's quite possible. I'm still unclear about it from how the OP describes that the user must become "an owner" of the device.

Comment: I'd expect that to be an attribute of the device, with a foreign key to the user table.

Comment: I might be confusing myself over the entire question.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ the following model...

[image]

...to ensure that:

- There are multiple devices per user, but **at most** one active device per user, simply because `ActiveDeviceNo` is in the same row as the user.
- On a DBMS that supports deferred foreign keys, this model can also enforce **exactly** one active device per user (by making `ActiveDeviceNo` NOT NULL).
- The device that is active for a user is guaranteed to belong to the **same** user. This is achieved by employing an *identifying relationship* that carries `UserId` from user to device, which is then carried back to the user and "merged" with the original `UserId`.

This model if very [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index)-friendly. If the PK is used as a clustering key, getting all the devices of the given user will incur minimal I/O due to the fact that devices of the same user are stored physically close together in the database. It also naturally represents the per-user order of devices (if that's important).

This is about straightforward and space-efficient as it gets, but forces certain tradeoffs in the key design:

- The modification of the key is required when the device is moved to another user, which may need to be cascaded to other tables that reference it. Also, the key is "fatter", making foreign keys in referencing tables fatter. You can always add a [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) (`DeviceId`) to the device, then reference *it* from other tables, if avoiding these kinds of issues is important.
- While you can just use auto-increment for `DeviceNo`, this is not completely optimal and can produce numbers larger than necessary (and waste space if variable-length representation of numbers is supported by the DBMS). OTOH, finding the more optimal value for `DeviceNo` can be somewhat cumbersome in a concurrent environment.

---

Other than that, you could either employ a filtered/partial unique index with "is active" flag (as others have suggested), or if your DBMS doesn't support that, you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Device (
    DeviceId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId INT REFERENCES User (UserId),
    ActiveUserId INT UNIQUE,
    CHECK (ActiveUserId IS NULL OR ActiveUserId = UserId)
);
```

This works because UNIQUE constraint ignores NULL values (assuming your DBMS treats NULLs correctly).